# Creating numbered dictionaries with a For loop [python]

Tags: python, dictionary

For 18 different links, I'm trying to create 18 different dictionaries (one for each area of land demarcated in the links) which each contain keys and values for statistics like population, housing units in area, etc.  The key is the name of the statistic, and the value is the value.  I've written the part that iterates through all 18 links and retrieves the population and housing units (and their values), but I can't figure out how to make the dictionaries.  I tried using a for loop like so:

```
def bgScrape(self):
        i = 0
        for l in self.hrefs:
            html = urlopen('http://www.usa.com' + l)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
            stat = soup.find('table')
            stat = stat.find_next('table')
            population = stat.find('td')
            population = population.find_next('td')
            population1 = population.find_next('a')
            population1 = population1.find_next('a')
            houseunits = population1.find_next('td')
            houseunits1 = population1.find_next('a')
            print(houseunits1)
            for i in range(18):
                stats[i] = {}
                stats[i]['Population'] = population1.text
```

but this gives me `NameError: name 'stats' is not defined`, which has led me to believe you can't make dictionaries in a For loop like this.  Is this the case, or am I just writing it incorrectly?  Or is there a better way to achieve this goal entirely?

Comment: Well, where is `stats`? Is it some global variable somewhere, or is it not defined at all?

Comment: I think you should define `stats` as a list before the second for loop

Comment: @LoïcG., when I do that it gives me an IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Of course, because your list doesn't contains any element and you try to access to an index ... You should use the `append` method to add elements to the list. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the whole second loop

```
for i in range(18):
    stats[i] = {}
    stats[i]['Population'] = population1.text
```

by :

```
stats = [{'Population' : population1.text} for i in range(18)]
```

Comment: This works, but gives me 18 dicts each with 18 'Population' keys.

Comment: I've just edited my answer. I don't know what dit you expect. I just corrected your code to make it work

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!